my gmail account got added as recovery to someone else without my permission?
i got this email from google "Verify your Google Account contact email address" at 4:14pm,
saying "If you didn't add myemailaddres@gmail.com to your Google Account, ignore this email and that address won't be added to your Google Account.", this email body also has a big blue "verify contact email" button, which i never clicked, i didnt even open this email until much later.
then same at 4:14pm, i get second email "Someone added you as their recovery email", with text "If you don’t recognize this account, it’s likely your email address was added in error. You can remove your email address from that account. Disconnect email".
"added in error"? i am confused, how can this happen? Is google bugged and they dont know it?
both email were from Google no-reply@accounts.google.com, signed-by:  accounts.google.com
security:    Standard encryption (TLS)
both emails have this:
SPF:    PASS with IP *..220.73 Learn more
DKIM:   'PASS' with domain accounts.google.com Learn more
DMARC:  'PASS' Learn more
following is what i would assume is the header of email:
Delivered-To: ***@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a05:6358:9a02:b0:1b8:3dec:17d5 with SMTP id p2csp1232161rwa;
        Sun, 6 Oct 2024 04:14:11 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 2002:a05:6a21:2d09:b0:1cc:e7a2:2bef with SMTP id adf61e73a8af0-1d6dfa48a6fmr14542417637.30.1728213251316;
        Sun, 06 Oct 2024 04:14:11 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1728213251; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20240605;
        b=VTJF7UfilkCuGyexX7bRvrgXd/g75h/BOBD22hDO5vjpS0CFQjs+QlrkxSHAAkxiY1
         UbeWj5COBKLytIw2KJSsa7GckkIjsKZjprlJmEgC2UCQX/+rhvOwnEfYqEZ+JdUlChan
         nhluHyzTlfl2uioWxf9WTGlVLzIrj8hT0gJSivnp+hnVo4e0HEzgsIpQ8Bc1HY1z28qq
         Q3O1IarMV7imdtaV9vVwPqlSuQi/bTnDkx54xjK7q+c0QqZ6Vz+duiuChl7iQzWmg6cj
         uPbDsS++DbhQ3Xo/noFM2ZfCuW4zdAYeEm6e26SAWKT98R1FJbosIBtovlY82D8NhJpW
         GoHA==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20240605;
        h=to:from:subject:message-id:reachouttracker:feedback-id:date
         :mime-version:dkim-signature;
        bh=Zw3r/vpHmRZmua5oqE2qz56J1kW4MirPYw7JPAhqKa4=;
        fh=tw2uBeoGpkUq/izt4mbKCVdY/n9XtNTAZH9MEwruEZE=;
        b=I0ujtotIqt4z+VNQei4NPqdbgNvard4yPQ+AiJQI3Rs5o12/oGVFP15B5PA/6C51m/
         uWpOo55yKoq5jqJ5jX4SS/MGYJdA8V4em/maRP9YN4aj1ZSr+J0xSm6gHTMhUEhZxNOe
         WDHQIQMFosYVz095uSCxA8XsecdUemogT3pcmtWEPqkt9UV/ypkRT4nNItr9pxiOKD6+
         JNbTBrjl40VzsioqQrOCjrb6iJkgN/FnSkT2xnLqS3VcbU+Er+4NULVf+6vl5nOHJ7tt
         xHNqLVXUQb8+d8el4qAglcrQImm2TzGySbaC2UqVK4l5UmGB3bgt29Jbj6izq+l+aVLf
         zXHw==;
        dara=google.com
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@accounts.google.com header.s=20230601 header.b=ZHH8NPFn;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of 3aneczwgtcs0wx-anyuhjllxdwcb.pxxpun.lxvjkdkjtjavpvjru.lxv@identity-reachout.bounces.google.com designates ***.**.220.69 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=3AnECZwgTCS0WX-aNYUhJLLXdWcb.PXXPUN.LXVJKdKJTJaVPVJRU.LXV@identity-reachout.bounces.google.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=accounts.google.com;
       dara=pass header.i=@gmail.com
Return-Path: <3AnECZwgTCS0WX-aNYUhJLLXdWcb.PXXPUN.LXVJKdKJTJaVPVJRU.LXV@identity-reachout.bounces.google.com>
Received: from mail-sor-f69.google.com (mail-sor-f69.google.com. [***.**.220.69])
        by mx.google.com with SMTPS id d2e1a72fcca58-71df0cc3ab5sor2193778b3a.3.2024.10.06.04.14.11
        for <***@gmail.com>
        (Google Transport Security);
        Sun, 06 Oct 2024 04:14:11 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of 3aneczwgtcs0wx-anyuhjllxdwcb.pxxpun.lxvjkdkjtjavpvjru.lxv@identity-reachout.bounces.google.com designates ***.**.220.69 as permitted sender) client-ip=***.**.220.69;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@accounts.google.com header.s=20230601 header.b=ZHH8NPFn;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of 3aneczwgtcs0wx-anyuhjllxdwcb.pxxpun.lxvjkdkjtjavpvjru.lxv@identity-reachout.bounces.google.com designates ***.**.220.69 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=3AnECZwgTCS0WX-aNYUhJLLXdWcb.PXXPUN.LXVJKdKJTJaVPVJRU.LXV@identity-reachout.bounces.google.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=accounts.google.com;
       dara=pass header.i=@gmail.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=accounts.google.com; s=20230601; t=1728213251; x=1728818051; dara=google.com;
        h=to:from:subject:message-id:reachouttracker:feedback-id:date
         :mime-version:from:to:cc:subject:date:message-id:reply-to;
        bh=Zw3r/vpHmRZmua5oqE2qz56J1kW4MirPYw7JPAhqKa4=;
        b=ZHH8NPFnVyS8l3iRd/thJabmZGjZf1Pi8oklAjuXHnNr7U5ObwDR1HTa3kRSgN8fkl
         dPJDvVK1/9YxAKDbg3f1OmawWa+8UbzIqsmmzjXaKm0cfZwYEG+5UtXnk05j+3eK/Ou2
         Zp754wJyEGqDR8xeZJ6lMcqSwh8HNQjK/txiZHNQVmzXs34n+UMakE+D/rxotIuywYt5
         ONcllUoIinUpdp0SJ6KdfePGuQv4oo8GZwtupFfG0ZdoGVa4h7O5ESUEjYWVAa3M8q42
         icgDNGTT2iW1I2WCSnUnEuznyEL9Juv7cRPZrEWYZwIJ/vJ7pToIS++1ltCpsdcHxkoG
         zj8w==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20230601; t=1728213251; x=1728818051;
        h=to:from:subject:message-id:reachouttracker:feedback-id:date
         :mime-version:x-gm-message-state:from:to:cc:subject:date:message-id
         :reply-to;
        bh=Zw3r/vpHmRZmua5oqE2qz56J1kW4MirPYw7JPAhqKa4=;
        b=gORC7DKaMe1ww0mT79Lx0nu/PmtuONYfcVZNu0bVi3/Xf6avk55ixcKfoxGxyJ1n8o
         IPP0VVmd/AmMWQ20YcD5alW1bB6i2SSY/r5mGf395tD0ZJrvla1UCrP9CqGZyfNnXdSB
         croawdrtiMe+0TfL7uuQcXZazcdXOb1E80f18RYfoi6QlMBG82nJE1gHEBvD7u+4727h
         rhfo1ROeXD58wAo5fN3Ze7MeSpkK7EgZFI5jEpME+hy9BddZREoP6TMg5m1X0YASknTA
         Ly/yP9w5nuPig8NpePtSc82dX9Iw54z+z7kJOvrvTU/IZsLWjEbKX6sLQwCzTZjh3Yqa
         fq4A==
X-Gm-Message-State: AOJu0YxRjgOCyzSvbts671B3U5AP4SldsO6gvuKkAoPaMXwsAB6XqdIU qu5YWPXS4WJDgP/yvcQnHSI1ju8HAGE5dM+DsNpMEhYCzZfb+6XoL5pJDBGBli823eFzWFtEZne yqTdPH4up3nN3Z84IWp3H4UTM2qaqXPP4nEUaoT8PjXsBapDTsD6oOhxRoMBpPajMAwJW5VTPXZ Nw11D/u131C74xyQ==
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGHT+IFg7z0WlRK1CoD331B9OBMBBR61/RS0hpy7hUWKzUH2Mk45OcpB1pp4V/bZh3fXFW9nuw8bwsf68aI8CBQXmN6vevoaSKTftrQEaU7IPAk=
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 2002:a05:6a21:1192:b0:1cf:489a:52c1 with SMTP id adf61e73a8af0-1d6dfa3ba62mr11304982637.18.1728213250995; Sun, 06 Oct 2024 04:14:10 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2024 11:14:08 GMT
X-Account-Notification-Type: 2-RECOVERY
Feedback-ID: 2-RECOVERY:account-notifier
ReachoutTracker: AVkLUt1LGQM3d9HPN/4LWkVC3h1ydb79SXdwBtC9uj2RKwThUxMA5BOc5oCS4Ex1PYZSms/v8WHP9W2rHBYX2Eqi6H2XILoY
X-Notifications: 0d6ccdbe6dc20000
X-Notifications-Bounce-Info: AdZT3xQBU9j5eljF-8Cy9Bil8KP2Y-uIuAvR97paylyc3NKpWuIKkODsQ28ew_QvDrOMlZAykNTQCh7y4_ng-50pKpDJp1UOa4_-xfrwZyuSWU_pnhUDPMPQthoagqNrHr19xNr6aEpqmCpE-1RfTH6_cfs_lPJtrHKFqkpr-MGr-FaOzHSbpLjqh3eG4ORWLpo909nW-sE-EiCUrgJLQ-VX_Wa9-po9ZnqyVANjAwNjA0MDQxNTM1NTk2OTMzMg
Message-ID: <sPZJC3sfVp66Y1LO-OndXQ@notifications.google.com>
Subject: Someone added you as their recovery email
From: Google <no-reply@accounts.google.com>
To: ***@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000ec02ac0623cd004c"


Looks legit to me.

ok so what does this mean now, without me pressing the button in the email to allow for the verification (didnt even open that email), just a few seconds later it says ok i am now the recovery email for yet another account. Is my account hacked, or is there a bug in gmail that is being exploited by scammers that google doesnt know about. Should i contact google?

There are two possibilities here:

Legitimate
Someone tried to add your Gmail address as a recovery address for their Gmail account either intentionally or by mistake.
Phishing attempt 
This email is not from Google and is designed to trick you into clicking a link.

A.  Legitimate
It is most likely a legitimate email, either intentionally or a typo by the triggering account owner.

It's highly unlikely that Gmail would deliver a message like this if illegitimate, without flagging it as suspicious at a minimum, if delivered at all.
A legitimate message from Gmail's verification process to a Gmail address would need to be transported end-to-end on Google's servers, therefore a fake one would be easily identified by their abuse prevention systems.
You can verify the message yourself by looking at the original message.

The headers will tell you the route it took to get to you, and what verifications (SPF, DMARC, etc.) passed and failed.
The target URL for the verification link in the message will be displayed without the need to click on it, and you can confirm where it would have taken you.


The email you  recieved will list the account that triggered the message which may provide insight into why you were selected:

<somebody@gmail.com> wants your email address to be their recovery
email.



B.  Phishing attempt

While a remote possibility, this would be a poor choice of approaches as it is discourages you to click on the link.
A typical phishing attempt would encourage  you to click on a link.
It is unlikely a phishing attempt   such as this would arrive without Gmail flagging the message or blocking it (discussed in A.1. & A.2. above).


i added what i understand to be the header of email. i hope there is no sensitive info that i have shared there

This is a common phishing attempt simply to verify that an email address is valid. It's used to find domains that have catchall email addresses.  The spammer will then use that domain for any email generation needs that they have that require validating whether an email is valid or not.
Most of the answers you find online will be from complete idiots that have no idea whats actually going on.  My guess is you probably have this type of setup.  I get them all the time and simply never respond to them.  They dont care about losing that gmail account,  all they care about is monitoring to see if the email they added mysteriously turns up missing, in which case, they know they've found a valid email.
